# A question concerning derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives

What is the derivative of $x(2x^2 - 3)^4$

My answer is

$x(2x^2 - 3)^4 = (2x^3 - 3x)^4 = 4(2x^3 - 3x)^3 . (6x^2 - 3) = (24x^2 - 12)(2x^3 -3x)^3$

the correct answer is suppose to be:

$16x^2(2x^2-3)^3+(2x^2-3)^4$

Comment: Note the step $x(2x^2-3)^4=(2x^3-3x)^4$ is incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(x\times(2x^2 - 3)^4)'= x'\times((2x^2-3)^4) + x\times((2x^2-3)^4)'$
I think you can take it from here on, and read how to derivative $(f(x)\times g(x))'$.

Comment: oh I got it thanks!

Comment: No problem. Glad to help.I recommend http://www.amazon.co.uk/Schaums-000-Solved-Problems-Calculus/dp/0071635343 for a begginer it's problems aren't hard but are explained pretty well.

Answer (score 2):

Well first of all you cannot just bring in the $x$ inside. $x(2x^2-3)^4\neq (2x^3-3x)^4$. The second hint I am going to tell you is to use the product rule and the chain rule.

Answer (score 1):

If the original function is $h(x)$, then

$$h'(x) = g'(x)f(x) + g(x)f'(x)$$ because of product rule, where $g(x) = x$ and $f(x) = (2x^2 - 3)^4$.

$g'(x)$ is then $1$, and $f'(x)$ is $16x(2x^2 - 3)^3$.

So,

$(2x^2 - 3)^4 + 16x^2(2x^2 - 3)^3$

Comment: Great answer. When I first started posting answers people recommended me to give hints instead of full answers.

Comment: Good point :). I'll keep that in mind.